# How to retrieve a unicode text from a text file?

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

I have a text file embedded in my executable binary so I want to at run-time to read the content:

In header file `myres.h`:

```
#define  UNICODE
#define _UNICODE

#define MY_RESOURCE    1000
```

In resource file `myres.rc`:

```
#include "myres.h"

MY_RESOURCE   RT_RCDATA   L"Help Topics.txt"
```

Now in `WinMain.cpp` in DialogBox that at WM_INITDIALOG loads the content and sets it to the edit control:

```
case WM_INITDIALOG:{
    HGLOBAL   res_handle = NULL;
    HRSRC     res;
    wchar_t*  res_data;
    DWORD     res_size;

    res = FindResourceW(GetModuleHandleW(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCEW(MY_RESOURCE), (LPWSTR)RT_RCDATA);
    if (!res)
        return 1;

    res_handle = LoadResource(NULL, res);
    if (!res_handle)
        return 2;

    res_data = (wchar_t*)LockResource(res_handle);
    res_size = SizeofResource(NULL, res);

    SendDlgItemMessageW(hWnd, ID_HELP_CONTENT, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)res_data);

    return TRUE;        
}
break;
```

Now when the dialog is created it fills the edit control with  unreadable characters like Chinese ones.

Note If I use the ANSI version of loading the content and undefining UNICODE the code works fine but I need UNICODE.

- The content of the text file is saved as `UTF-8 BOM`.

Is there a way around? - Some recommends me to use `MultiByteToWideChar()` but I don't know why and how?

If so why other controls I can send them UNICODE text and retrieve it from them without any other stuff eg:

```
SendDlgItemMessageW(hWnd, ID_HELP_CONTENT, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)L"Chinese/arabic/latin... text here");
```

Why above works but when loading the text from a text file doesn't print correctly?

Comment: Add at least comment when voting down.

Comment: You need to break this up. You have extracted from the resource an array of bytes that is UTF8 encoded. Now you need to convert to UTF16. Strip away all the resource code and you have a simple question. How to convert from UTF8 to UTF16. A question that has been asked many times before.

Comment: Your text file is UTF-8 and the MS-Windows Unicode APIs expect UTF-16LE you will need to convert either the file before storing it or the bytes from UTF-8 to UTF-16LE after reading it in.

Comment: @RichardCritten: How to convert it to `UTF-16L`?

Comment: @Won Richard offered you two choices. Convert before compiling resource. Or convert after extracting resource. Conversion process is different for both. You are panicking and flailing around. Think.

Comment: See the 1st parameter to `MultiByteToWideChar` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx  Or to pre-convert the text file use the `Save as...` command in Notepad and choose the encoding `Unicode`.

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/).

Comment: Thank you all guys. You are always as usual so helpful. I figure it through converting my text file to `UTF-16LE` Now it works fine.

Comment: On a side note, in your `.rc` file, you need to specify the resource type as `RCDATA` instead of `RT_RCDATA`.  `RT_RCDATA` is a constant that you pass to `FindResource()`, not to `rc.exe`.